# Having multiple websites running from the same script

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, symlink

I have 4 sites/domains which are all running from a single code base. My `dir` structure is as follows:

- www/mainsite (parent site all code is in one place)
- www/site1    (child sites with a custom settings file and images folder)
- www/site2    (child sites with a custom settings file and images folder)
- www/site3    (child sites with a custom settings file and images folder)

Currently each child site has the same `dir` structure. Such as `contact-us/index` or `projects/index` The index files are just simple `includes` which point to the `mainsite`. (each of child sites share the same content)

Is there a way I can set this up without copying all of these `dir` for each child site (since they are all the same), I would prefer to just have it in one place.

From research I think I can do this using a `symlink`. Is this the best way? What are alternative methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will helpful for you

You can redirect with  `[OR]`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain4.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain5.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This will redirect all your domains to your to your main domain

Ref URL : http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/301-redirect/multiple-domain-names/